# Matrix , np.transpose

Tags: python, matrix, jupyter

> I have a project to build a Facial Recognition system. I have to: load the images from folder, put them as matrix ,do a global matrix with all images, having one image per column. The np.transpose isnt working

```
# the global matrix
database_matrix = []

# loading all images in folder
for file in os.listdir("Database"):
    filename = "Database/" + file
    # opening image
    image = Image.open(filename)
    # converting to array
    image_array = np.array(image)
    # flatten to 1D
    image_array_flatten = image_array.flatten()
    # finally add to global matrix
    database_matrix.append(image_array_flatten)

# transpose to get one image por column
np.transpose(database_matrix)
```

Comment: How "np.transpose isnt working" ?

Comment: it doesn t do anything at all, the matrix keeps the same

Comment: You have to assign the transposed array to a variable name. np.transpose returns the transposed array, it doesn't change it in place.

Comment: Still doesnt work, i tried 
dmt = np.transpose(database_matrix)
print(dmt) and go the same result

Comment: Your database_matrix is a list. try to convert it to an np.array first and transpose it afterwards database_matrix = np.array(database_matrix).T  should do the trick